# Does cooking kitniyot in a pot render it non-kosher-for-Passover for Ashkenazic Jews? If so, why?

Tags: passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume, minhag, kashrut-kosher

I've heard of cases where a Sephardic family, for whom rice is totally kosher for Passover (assuming it's checked and contains no additives etc.), cooked rice in a pot. The next day, they invite their Ashkenazic neighbors over and cook completely kitniyot-free, but their Ashkenazic neighbors say it's a problem as even potatoes cooked in that "kitniyot" pot is a problem.

Am I getting this correct so far?

If so, is there any halachic basis to this, or is it "just one of those Passover customs"?

This should, in theory, be far better than a case of a non-kosher pot; by some quick back-of-envelope math, for any normal pot I can think of, the ratio of volume-of-the-pot-material-itself against volume-contained-within-the-pot should be far less than 50%.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those that cited OC 453 are correct: the Mishna Berura in Se'if Katan 8 states clearly that if rice was found in soup, just throw out the rice, and you may eat the soup.  The same applies for a pot that was used to cook kitnios for a child that must have kitnios on Pesach.  Whether lechatchila you may use the pot is debatable.  The Feinsteins hold that one should not use the pot lechatchila, but if it has been used, one may eat the food lechatchila.

I would hesitate to cite Sfardic poskim on this issue.  Some denigrate the Ashkenazic minhag of kitniyos and therefore rely on mattirim that we would not necessarily consider.

Comment: Thanks Barzilai. So it's a "mevatlin issur lechatchila" issue more or less to use the pot?

Comment: Exactly.  But after the fact, it's not a problem at all, because we rely on the biggest leniencies possible in bittul of the flavor of Kitniyos.

Comment: Barzilai, did you mistakenly write "bitul of the flavor"?

Comment: Barzilai, what YDK is getting at is that there is no issue of bitul of flavor when it comes to kitniyos; it is batel berov which has nothing to do with flavor.

Answer (score 3):

hazon ovadia pesah page פו
an ashkenazi can eat at a sepharadi even if he cooked rice on the pot
see there if you want more mecorot of understand the mahloket

on the other hand I heard from a friend that the rabanim ashkenazim are mahmir on this, but I don't have any source

Comment: R' Herschel Shachter is one source.  Only within 24 hrs though.

Answer (score 2):

Kitniyot is not chametz - Keilim used for Kitniyot are not assur for Ashkenazim  - In fact I recall one major Rishon (I have to find the citation) who wrote that if an Ashkenazi is served a soup on Pesach that has rice in it, he merely needs to remove the rice and can eat the rest of the soup.

There is no requirement to sell Kitniyot for Pesach or Keilim used for Kitniyot (in fact - someone who sold their kitniyot might be violating the issur of Bal Tosif).

See also [הלכות כשרות לפסח](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=744).  Section Nun-Vav  which cites the Shulchan Aruch 453:1

As the person who is preparing the food (the sephardi) has no issur of kitniyot, then any miniscule kitniyot residue is still considered a permitted item for him, so all rules of batel b'rov would still apply to him.

Comment: Josh H., Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks for bringing in this source! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish here: http://mi.yodeya.com/users/login

Comment: And does not seem to need bitul taam: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14165&st=&pgnum=92&hilite=

Comment: Josh, Bal Tosif of what Mitzvah? There is no mitzvah to sell your chometz!

Comment: Acc. to Ramban, even making up a mitzva would be BT.  Although that wouldn't apply here, since he doesn't think he's doing a d'Oraisa.

Answer (score -2):

I would say it has to do with Chometz is Assur B'Mashehu. Since we are very Makpid on Pesach therefore we do not do so.

I come from a family that does not eat Gebruks, however my wife's family does. The first Pesach I went to my in laws I asked Rabbi Hillel David how to deal with it. He said that on dishes they used, so long it is washed well I can use it too. However for pots and pans the ones that had Gebruks made in them I should not use over Pesach.

Comment: So you're saying effectively, if I understand correctly: "Even though Mr. Sefardi is certain there's no wheat in his rice, I have to behave as if there is", therefore minuscule amounts would be a problem; and not "Mr. Sefardi's rice is wheat-free, but my custom is not to eat rice" (in which case minuscule amounts wouldn't be).

Comment: It sounds right

Comment: The problem is the halacha clearly states that kitniyos is batel b'rov.

Comment: Pre Pesach it is Botel Brov. On Pesach we are Nizhar on a Mashehu.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14165&st=&pgnum=41

Comment: Gershon, can you clarify the source where that applies to kitnios?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14165&st=&pgnum=92&hilite=   There doesn't seem to be a distinction.

Comment: Gershon Gold, you are absolutely wrong. We are not nizhar on a mashehu of kitniyos on Pesach. It is a Halacha Mefureshes in the Rema that if the kitniyos oil dripped into your food on Pesach it is batel berov. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14165&st=&pgnum=92 and onto the next page.

Comment: My answer was an explanation to the question, not a Halachic rendering.

Comment: Gershon, you wrote in your comment "Pre Pesach it is Botel Brov. On Pesach we are Nizhar on a Mashehu" as an explanation to your explanation of the question. So, run that by me again: If kitniyos is batel berov on Pesach, how do you explain the hanhagah not to use kitniyos pots on Pesach based on the non-existent issur bemashehu of kitniyos?

Comment: @Yahu @gershon gold From this debate it is evident that kitniyot is a davar charif.  (This is in jest in case anyone didn't realize)